# Charts are not getting displayed on different slides

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am having a slight problem with my slideshow for the d3js charts that I am trying to display in different slides. The problem is that both of my charts are showing up in one slide instead of getting displayed in different slides. I double checked all div tags to make sure if all of them are closed. Not sure what am I missing here?

P.S. I know scripts are duplicated but I will be doing code clean-up after I fix the slideshow issue. Please bear with me on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing here, unlike my solution for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51471140/5768908), is that `d3.csv` is **asynchronous**. Because of that, your approach (selecting the div where the script is) won't work: there will be pollution and conflicts in the global scope.

A very easy workaround is using IIFEs, like this:

```
(function foo(){
    //your code here
}());
```

Let's see it. Here is your HTML and a silly bar chart I made, without the IIFEs. The blue chart should appear in the 3rd div and the red one in the 4th, but you can see that instead of that both charts show up in the last div:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Slides</title>
    <!-- Required stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <div id="filter"><b>States:</b></div>
        <script>
            var container = document.currentScript.parentNode;
            var svg = d3.select(container)
              .append("svg");
            d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/xv0yy", function(data) {
              var scale = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(data)
                .range([0, 300])
                .padding(0.4);
              var bars = svg.selectAll(null)
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .attr("x", d => scale(d))
                .attr("width", scale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", d => 150 - d)
                .attr("y", Number)
            })
         
        </script>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <script>
            var container = document.currentScript.parentNode;
            var svg = d3.select(container)
              .append("svg");
            d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/zgway", function(data) {
              var scale = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(data)
                .range([0, 300])
                .padding(0.4);
              var bars = svg.selectAll(null)
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .style("fill", "tomato")
                .attr("x", d => scale(d) + 10)
                .attr("width", scale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", d => 150 - d)
                .attr("y", Number)
            })
          
        </script>
      </div>
      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
      var slideIndex = 1;
      showSlides(slideIndex);

      function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
      }

      function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
      }

      function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
          slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Now the same code, but using the IIFEs, everything shows up in the correct place:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Slides</title>
    <!-- Required stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <div id="filter"><b>States:</b></div>
        <script>
          (function iife() {
            var container = document.currentScript.parentNode;
            var svg = d3.select(container)
              .append("svg");
            d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/xv0yy", function(data) {
              var scale = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(data)
                .range([0, 300])
                .padding(0.4);
              var bars = svg.selectAll(null)
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .attr("x", d => scale(d))
                .attr("width", scale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", d => 150 - d)
                .attr("y", Number)
            })
          }())
        </script>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <script>
          (function iife() {
            var container = document.currentScript.parentNode;
            var svg = d3.select(container)
              .append("svg");
            d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/zgway", function(data) {
              var scale = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(data)
                .range([0, 300])
                .padding(0.4);
              var bars = svg.selectAll(null)
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .style("fill", "tomato")
                .attr("x", d => scale(d))
                .attr("width", scale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", d => 150 - d)
                .attr("y", Number)
            })
          }())
        </script>
      </div>
      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
      var slideIndex = 1;
      showSlides(slideIndex);

      function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
      }

      function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
      }

      function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
          slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

In those snippets I'm using `d3.json`, not `d3.csv`, but the principle is the same.

---

PS: I cannot emphasise this enough: my answer for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51471140/5768908) was just a *curiosity*, so to speak. Do not follow the approach you're following here (using `document.currentScript`). This may be a nightmare to maintain/debug in the future.

Comment: I tried the solution in second snipped and it works as expected. There is a slight problem as in the first chart x-axis line disappeared. Gonna look into that why it is happening ? Appreciate for staying with me on this.